# Open CV ERR_NEED_MORE_IMGS

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, image-stitching

I am struggling implementing Open CV image stitching into my IOS app. I am using Xcode 7.1. The problem I am having is that I pass stitcher::Stitch an array containing 3 images in order for it to stitch the images, but then it returns a status code of: ERR_NEED_MORE_IMGS. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, here is my code:

```
+(UIImage *) stitchImages:(UIImage *)image :(UIImage *) imageTwo :(UIImage *) imageThree
{

cv::Mat matImageOne;
cv::Mat matImageTwo;
cv::Mat matImageThree;
cv::Mat imgOut;

cv::Stitcher stitcher = cv::Stitcher::createDefault(TRUE);
std::vector<cv::Mat> images;

UIImage *panoImage;

UIImageToMat(image, matImageOne);
UIImageToMat(imageTwo, matImageTwo);
UIImageToMat(imageThree, matImageThree);

matImageOne = cv::Mat::zeros(matImageOne.size(), CV_8UC3);
matImageTwo = cv::Mat::zeros(matImageTwo.size(), CV_8UC3);
matImageThree = cv::Mat::zeros(matImageThree.size(), CV_8UC3);

images.push_back(matImageOne);
images.push_back(matImageTwo);
images.push_back(matImageThree);

cv::Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.stitch(images, imgOut);

if(status == cv::Stitcher::Status::OK) { //Here the status is being returned as ERR_NEED_MORE_IMGS

    return MatToUIImage(imgOut);
}
else{
    return 0;
}
return image;
}
```

The images I am using is the top 2 images when you follow this ulr: https://ramsrigoutham.com/2012/11/22/panorama-image-stitching-in-opencv/
Thanx in advance!

Comment: Is it supposed to work with empty images?  Why not try using some example images instead?

Comment: I am sending through images as paramaters: image, imageTwo and imageThree. So the images are not empty.

Comment: Stitcher sets this status when it cannot stitch provided images. Usually, it is when there is small number of features on images. Could you provide your sample images?

Comment: I have attached a url that contains the 2 images. =D